# Is it possible to make JSF restore user entered values regardless of the data being valid?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am working on a JSF app with a form:

```
<h:inputText value="#{model.firstname}" />
<h:inputText value="#{model.employeeNumber}" converter="javax.faces.Integer"/>
...
```

Here's the model with bean validation:

```
@NotNull(message="Please enter a surname")
private String firstname;

@Min(value=1)
@Max(value=2000)
private Integer employeeNumber;
...
//setters and getters
```

Everything is working nicely apart from the explicitly coded 'back' button within the page which goes to the previous page / form.

I want the values the user entered to restore when they return to the above page again regardless of whether the data is valid.for example, if the user enters `abc` into the `employeeNumber` field this String cannot be stored to the `Integer` on the model.

I understand that JSF stores user entered values into "Request Values" for each `UIComponent`. It is these I would like to restore rather than that of my model because the above form had not had it's data validated yet.

How can I do this?

(data validation will happen when the user clicks submit).

Comment: Isn't it just browser's `autocomplete`? Add `autocomplete="off"` if you don't want this.

Comment: Hi, no, it's sort of the opposite I want. I want the data to re-appear on a page that the user has partially filled and navigated away from without validating that data and then returned. As if the user never navigated away and can continue filling out the form and then validate.

Comment: You can use form bean (with String) for storing user data and save data into model on submit action. If form bean has session scope, then it should work as you expected.

Comment: This can easily be done client side with e.g. [HTML5 local storage](https://google.com/search?q=html5+localstorage+save+form). Is this acceptable? If you really want to do it server side, then it becomes a bit more convoluted.

Comment: I think it would be best done server side for security. My colleague has just mentioned there may be a way to accomplish this using omnifaces.

Comment: Only if bean properties are all of `String` type, which is not the case here and thus require major changes in model. There is technically absolutely no way to store e.g. a non-number in an `Integer` property.

Comment: Thanks. That's just the scenario I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: It should theoretically be possible to manually save the component tree, carry around that in a serialized form and then restore it at a later point. I will perhaps experiment with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My colleague has just mentioned there may be a way to accomplish this using omnifaces*

As of now, there is. Lot of things were already available in OmniFaces except of only one small missing key part. I just [committed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/3e4ce01c6ddaaf3316c763a6c3dfc574a631cfc3) a `Hacks#getStateHelper()` to 2.3 SNAPSHOT which should expose the protected [`UIComponent#getStateHelper()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getStateHelper--) method into public. Then, it's doable together with help of [`EditableValueHolderStateHelper`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/component/EditableValueHolderStateHelper.html) already in OmniFaces since 1.0 and with [`<o:form>` and `<o:ignoreValidationFailed>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/ignoreValidationFailed) in order to invoke action anyway irrespective of conversion/validation errors (as the "back" button should do).

So, if you make sure you use at least OmniFaces 2.3 (currently only available as SNAPSHOT), then you can achieve the requirement with below session scoped helper bean, utilizing several OmniFaces utility classes `Faces`, `Hacks` and `EditableValueHolderStateHelper`:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Forms implements Serializable {

    private transient Map<String, StateHelper> states = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void saveState(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        UIComponent form = event.getComponent();
        FacesContext context = Faces.getContext();
        StateHelper state = Hacks.getStateHelper(form);
        EditableValueHolderStateHelper.save(context, state, form.getFacetsAndChildren());
        states.put(Faces.getViewId(), state);
    }

    public void restoreState(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        StateHelper state = states.get(Faces.getViewId());

        if (state != null) {
            UIComponent form = event.getComponent();
            FacesContext context = Faces.getContext();
            EditableValueHolderStateHelper.restore(context, state, form.getFacetsAndChildren());
        }
    }

    public void removeState() {
        states.remove(Faces.getViewId());
    }

}
```

The `saveState` needs to be invoked during `postValidate` event of the form component. The `restoreState()` needs to be invoked during `postAddToView` event of the form component. The `removeState()` needs to be invoked during succesful action. Below is an example form:

```
<o:form>
    <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{forms.restoreState}" />
    <f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{forms.saveState}" />

    <h:inputText value="#{bean.string}" required="true" />
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.integer}" required="true" />

    <h:commandButton value="save" actionListener="#{forms.removeState()}" action="#{bean.save}" />
    <h:commandButton value="back" action="#{bean.back}">
        <o:ignoreValidationFailed />
    </h:commandButton>

    <h:messages />
</o:form>
```

Major advantage of this approach is that **no modifications** needs to be made to existing validation rules and backing beans, hereby thus keeping all advantages of JSF and BV.

Make sure you clear server session state and/or increase `serialVersionUID` of `Forms` class whenever you make changes in the component tree structure of the associated forms, else you'll have to make prechecks and/or properly handle exceptions. Giving the forms and input components a fixed ID is also [strongly recommended](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/viewhandlers/NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler).

Answer (score 2):

I have dealt with just this problem in the past - by not using the validation annotations such as `@NotNull`, `@Min`, and `@Max`.  When using those annotations, invalid data cannot be applied to the model, and so the state cannot be saved on the server.

Instead, I had to code the validation logic in the method behind the Submit button.  The downside is that JSF isn't doing the work for you; you have to do it yourself.  The upside is that you have more control over exactly when and how the validation is applied.

Comment: How did you save invalid values of `Integer` and `BigDecimal` based properties? This is exactly where this question was all about.

Comment: I wasn't dealing specifically with that problem, but one approach is to bind the form to String properties, and then attempt to parse the strings into the destination numeric properties when Submit is clicked.

Comment: Another approach is to use Javascript to prevent non-numeric values from even being entered into the field.

Comment: JavaScript can be disabled/modified/spoofed by enduser. Your approach is not robust and destroys all advantages of JSF and BV.

Comment: This isn't using JavaScript as a security precaution; it is using it as a way to avoid hitting JSF validation errors.  If a user wants to shoot himself in the foot by hacking the JavaScript, that's his problem.